# Is there way to set default value to prop which is child of required prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I want to set default value to `size` prop, but it is child of required prop so I get error. Is there any workaround except disabling rule in eslint?

```
static propTypes = {
        widget: PropTypes.shape({
            config: PropTypes.shape({
                size: PropTypes.string
            }).isRequired
        }).isRequired,
    };
```

```
static defaultProps = {
        widget: PropTypes.shape({
            config: PropTypes.shape({
                size: 's'
            })
        })
    }
```

Eslint error

```
defaultProp "widget" defined for isRequired propType.eslint(react/default-props-match-prop-types)
```

Comment: it should just  be the value want to be the default : `widget:{config: {size:  's'}}`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, error still exist

Comment: just checked  error, you can't add a default value to a field that is required, instead, you can make it optional and add the default, then anybody using it must follow the shape.  Remove the widget required

Comment: you are defining propTypes again in defaultProps .. defaultProps = { widget:{config:{size:'s'}}}

Comment: yeah, if I delete required it will work, but I want to be sure that components which use this component will send config so I can't delete required

Comment: @KostyaTresko you should decide what you want. If you want to be sure that parent component will send config, then delete `defaultProps`. You must use `defaultProps` only for not required props.

Answer (score 0):

First observation you can simply just set the value of the default like so:

```js
widget: {
config: {size: 's'}
}
```

Secondly, according to the error, no point setting a default for a required field since it will and must be set when it was not provided by the caller via the `defaultProps`

So, maybe make the `widget` propTypes to optional then the error should not be there, but the shape is maintained when an invalid shape is passed in via props

Comment: yeah, if I delete required it will work, but I want to be sure that components which use this component will send config so I can't delete required

Comment: you can still keep the required of the config in the proptypes definition

Comment: maybe just move `config` out from widget props definition and make it required and not set a default for it